# How can I query for a sequence of values in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a daily record of consumption for every day of a year i.e. 365 records.

I am looking for 10 consecutive zeros in the above - i.e. 10 days in a row where consumption is zero. I just need to know if such a sequence exists. I need to do this efficiently as I will have to do this for a lot of meters.

This is the table, with some example data (with a sequence to be found between 2014-05-29 and 2014-06-10):

```
CREATE TABLE `Daily` (
`ID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`MeterID` int(10) default NULL,
`TimeStamp` datetime default NULL,
`Value1` double default NULL
)
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`) (index)


id          meterID value1      TimeStamp  
195142074   54438   246.492604  2014-05-01 00:00:00  
195142075   54438   29.844396   2014-05-02 00:00:00  
195142076   54438   0           2014-05-07 00:00:00  
195142077   54438   1.105348    2014-05-08 00:00:00  
195142078   54438   0           2014-05-09 00:00:00  
195142079   54438   79.585056   2014-05-27 00:00:00  
195142080   54438   1.105348    2014-05-28 00:00:00  
195142081   54438   0           2014-05-29 00:00:00  
195142082   54438   0           2014-05-30 00:00:00 
195142082   54438   0           2014-05-31 00:00:00
195142083   54438   0           2014-06-01 00:00:00
195142084   54438   0           2014-06-02 00:00:00
195142085   54438   0           2014-06-03 00:00:00
195142086   54438   0           2014-06-04 00:00:00
195142087   54438   0           2014-06-05 00:00:00
195142088   54438   0           2014-06-06 00:00:00
195142089   54438   0           2014-06-07 00:00:00
195142090   54438   0           2014-06-08 00:00:00
195142091   54438   0           2014-06-09 00:00:00
195142092   54438   0           2014-06-10 00:00:00   
195142093   54438   1.105348    2014-06-11 00:00:00  
..... (365 records in total)
```

Comment: You try to make -  date as concat sting, or just column of any date where last 10 days consumption = 0? if consecutive zeros > 10 days - for example 14days, it is till one or for each from - 11,12,13,14 it own list?

Answer (score 1):

just 9 joins
if ID is indexed the join will be efficient
if you have gaps in ID that needs to be compressed then this does not work

```
select row1.* 
from table row1 
join table row2 
      on row2.id = row1.id + 1
     and row1.value = 0 
     and row2.value = 0
join table row3 
      on row3.id = row1.id + 2
     and row3.value = 0 
join table row4 
      on row4.id = row1.id + 3
     and row4.value = 0 
...
join table row10
      on row10.id = row1.id + 9
     and row10.value = 0
```

if no negative values

```
 select row1.id
   from table row1 
   join table row2 
         on row2.id >= row1.id 
        and row2.id <= row1.id + 10 
  group by row1.id 
 having sum(row2.value) = 0
```

Comment: This assumes the `ids` have no gaps.

Comment: @RickJames No kidding - line 3.  "if you have gaps in ID that needs to be compressed then this does not work"

Answer (score 1):

if need just date:

```
SELECT * FROM daily WHERE TimeStamp IN (
SELECT
    tt_1.TimeStamp
FROM
    daily tt_1
LEFT JOIN daily tt_2 ON tt_1.id = tt_2.id
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            sum(t_2.value1)
        FROM
            daily t_2
        WHERE
            t_2.TimeStamp >= DATE_SUB(tt_1.TimeStamp, INTERVAL 9 DAY)
        AND t_2.TimeStamp <= tt_1.TimeStamp AND t_2.MetterID = tt_1.MetterID HAVING COUNT(id) = 10
    ) = 0 )
```

result will be :

```
12  0   2015-11-12  1
28  0   2015-11-28  2
```

if as string of date:

```
SELECT tt1.MetterID, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(tt1.TimeStamp AS CHAR) SEPARATOR  ', ' ) AS dates_with_zero_consuption FROM daily tt1 
RIGHT JOIN

(SELECT TimeStamp FROM daily
WHERE TimeStamp IN (
SELECT
    tt_1.TimeStamp
FROM
    daily tt_1
LEFT JOIN daily tt_2 ON tt_1.id = tt_2.id
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            sum(t_2.value1)
        FROM
            daily t_2
        WHERE
            t_2.TimeStamp >= DATE_SUB(tt_1.TimeStamp, INTERVAL 9 DAY)
        AND t_2.TimeStamp <= tt_1.TimeStamp AND t_2.MetterID = tt_1.MetterID HAVING COUNT(id) = 10
    ) = 0 ) ) tt2

ON tt1.TimeStamp >= DATE_SUB(tt2.TimeStamp, INTERVAL 9 DAY) AND tt1.TimeStamp <= tt2.TimeStamp
GROUP BY 
-- tt1.MetterID, 
tt2.TimeStamp
ORDER BY t1.TimeStamp
```

with result as:

```
MetterID; dates_with_zero_consuption 
1   2015-11-04, 2015-11-10, 2015-11-05, 2015-11-11, 2015-11-06, 2015-11-12, 2015-11-07, 2015-11-08, 2015-11-03, 2015-11-09
2   2015-11-26, 2015-11-21, 2015-11-27, 2015-11-22, 2015-11-28, 2015-11-23, 2015-11-24, 2015-11-19, 2015-11-25, 2015-11-20
```

Test dataset:

```
id; Value1, TimeStamp; MetterID
1   1   2015-11-01  1
2   2   2015-11-02  1
3   0   2015-11-03  1
4   0   2015-11-04  1
5   0   2015-11-05  1
6   0   2015-11-06  1
7   0   2015-11-07  1
8   0   2015-11-08  1
9   0   2015-11-09  1
10  0   2015-11-10  1
11  0   2015-11-11  1
12  0   2015-11-12  1
13  1   2015-11-13  1
14  2   2015-11-14  1
15  3   2015-11-15  1
16  4   2015-11-16  2
17  5   2015-11-17  2
18  6   2015-11-18  2
19  0   2015-11-19  2
20  0   2015-11-20  2
21  0   2015-11-21  2
22  0   2015-11-22  2
23  0   2015-11-23  2
24  0   2015-11-24  2
25  0   2015-11-25  2
26  0   2015-11-26  2
27  0   2015-11-27  2
28  0   2015-11-28  2
29  0   2015-11-29  3
30  1   2015-11-30  3
```

Comment: This looks good, but is not executing forever on my huge table.

Comment: You not provide any additional information about table/indexes and etc. this will work with PROPER indexes on some (also BIG) data, for VERY HUGE - use principles and make stored procedure, which will go thru parts of table.

In original question - no index at all, of course it never finishing :)

Comment: Just add for zapper - on VERY HUGE table (I make this with multy millions rows tables), You still have 365 record for each meterID. Create procedure which select 365 records into table with indexes, run query, store result to report_table, go to next meter. It only one method for REALY HUGE tables. First of 2 examples - of course faster

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        ( SELECT d.*,
                @seq := IF(value1 = 0, @seq + 1, 0) AS seq
            FROM Daily AS d
            JOIN ( SELECT @seq := 0 ) AS initialization
            ORDER BY id
        ) AS x
    WHERE seq = 10;
```

That should find the 10th item in every sequence of 10 or more.  Run it to verify that it works for you.  Then wrap it in `EXISTS( )`, since you only want to know of a long sequence exists.

This is likely to be much faster than any technique with a `JOIN`.

Comment: And it is immune to gaps.